# Android Caller ID Device

Tags: java, android, react-native, caller-id

I have a caller id device as in the image. For Windows, this device works flawlessly. However, I need to get the phone number of the caller in my android application by connecting this device to the android device with otg cable. Does it support Android caller id devices or can I access the caller's phone number by listening to the usb port in my android application?

[image]